# How do I handle multipart/form-data from jsp in Spring controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I wanted to handle both the file and checkbox value of jsp page in my spring @Controller my mapping is as below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile/", method =  RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadFile(HttpServletRequest request,   @RequestParam("uploadToCheck") String uploadToCheck) {
```

jsp page:

```
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="/uploadFile/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="50"/>
<br /> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="uploadToCheck" id="uploadToCheck"/>   Upload data into db
<br />
```

In my spring controller, I could not get value for "uploadToCheck" using @RequestParam.

I had debug the REST call trace it as below.

```
------WebKitFormBoundary6EG9FuRGgpq4BwKj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="new-xcel.xls"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel


------WebKitFormBoundary6EG9FuRGgpq4BwKj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadToCheck"

on
------WebKitFormBoundary6EG9FuRGgpq4BwKj--
```

Does anyone know how to get value of both inputs which are in same form. It should be accessed in HttServletRequest object or @RequestParam right?
If not, then what is the alternative solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use @RequestPart for file and @RequestParam for check box like below on your controller.

```
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam boolean uploadToCheck, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) String uploadToCheck) {}
```

One more thing to remember. This will return true if the check box is checked. There are few different ways to handle checkboxes. Take a look at some of the examples and use it as per your need. I just provided an option as to how to get both file and checkbox value. Hope this helps.